# Adding a counter to controller. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 4 app. In the controller, I iterate through each assignment entry in the database to check if a requirement is associated with more than one assignment. However, I can't figure out how to add a counter, i.e. hit = 0, hit = 1, etc. to the controller.

EDIT: The relationship between assignment and requirement is HABTM.

My code is below:

```
def check_requirements
 @assignments = Assignment.all
 @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
 @requirement = Requirement.find(params[:requirement_id])
 @assignments.each do |assignment|
      if assignment.include(requirement)
        #here's where the counter should go
      end
  end
  if counter is greater than zero or one, do nothing
  else @assignment.delete(requirement)
end
```

Comment: What's the relation between Assignment and Requirement? Can you post the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check_requirements
 @assignments = Assignment.all
 @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
 @requirement = Requirement.find(params[:requirement_id])
 counter = 0
 @assignments.each do |assignment|
      if assignment.include(requirement)
        counter+=1
      end
  end
  if counter is greater than zero or one, do nothing
  else @assignment.delete(requirement)
end
```

Comment: Depending of what Megan wants, It's make more sense than my previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

```
def check_requirements
 @assignments = Assignment.all
 @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
 @requirement = Requirement.find(params[:requirement_id])
 @assignments.each_with_index do |assignment,hit|
      if assignment.include(requirement)
        p "hit : #{hit}"
      end
  end
  if counter is greater than zero or one, do nothing
  else @assignment.delete(requirement)
end
```

Comment: What does the p do in the "p 'hit: #{hit}'"?

Comment: It's just to print hit so you can see its value. I don't know what you want to do with hit. So replace this line by what you need.